# Order By ASC DateTimeOffset column from datatable C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I Filled the Data table from Data Lake. Now I trying to do order by ascending order on **eventDateTime** Column which of **DateTimeOffset**.

```
[eventDateTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL
```

> eventDateTime = "5/12/2022 11:21:06 AM +05:30"

I have tried below way

```
 var orderedRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      orderby  row.Field<DateTimeOffset>("eventDateTime")
                      select row; 
    DataTable tblOrdered = orderedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

However i got below exception :

```
Exception occured Function at messge Status queued ->Run-> Message:Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.DateTimeOffset'., StackTrace:   at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value)
```

I have tried below way however it didn't work:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "eventDateTime asc";
```

none of the above worked.

Comment: Can you provide a sample string for eventDateTime? Have you tried `orderby  DateTimeOffset.Parse(row.Field<string>("eventDateTime"))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Thank you for responding my question. here is the event DateTime value - "5/12/2022 11:21:06 AM +05:30"

Comment: If all strings are well formatted like this it should work as i have said in my first comment, since this works in Linqpad: `DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("5/12/2022 11:21:06 AM +05:30");`

Comment: Parse the date string : DateTime.Parse(eventDateTime("5/12/2022 11:21:06 AM +05:30")

Comment: @TimSchmelter, eventDateTime column is of DateTimeoffset type. How can we consider it as string and converting to datetimeoffset

Comment: @prasanthi: look at your own error message: Message:Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.DateTimeOffset'. So for whatever reason the .NET datatype for a sql datetimetoffset is string, not `DateTimeOffset`. But since i don't see where and how you fill the `DataTable` it could also be that the sql query is incorrect. Edit: according to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) the mapping is `datetimeoffset` > `DateTimeOffset`. So there is something wrong with your query or (if you use) your stored-procedure.